# Flutter iOS Google maps: weird appear animation

Tags: ios, google-maps, flutter

I'm having an issue with Flutter Google maps [official plugin](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/tree/master/packages/google_maps_flutter) on iOS both in debug and release builds which occurs when you open an app from a terminated state. No issue on Android

There's a weird appear animation playing when I have Google Map in my widget, especially it's annoying when there's a centered floating action button as well, it has some slide in animation too

Check this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=94ee6cePbWw&feature=youtu.be

If you play it frame by frame, you'll see that app bar is colored correctly, floating action button is drawn, but then everything is flashed white and floating action button suddenly plays a slide in appearing animation, when it was already displayed. It all looks very glitchy

If I remove Google map from my widget, everything works fine: there's no FAB slide in animation and app bar is not flashed white, after they were drawn.

Running on Flutter v1.1.4. I want to get rid of this appear animation, thanks for the support

Here's my code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: '',
      theme: ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.blue),
      home: MyHomePage(title: ''),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('')),
      body: GoogleMap(
        onMapCreated: (controller) {},
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {},
      ),
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerFloat,
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should realize that this is a developer preview.  Until the version number hits 1.0, all bets are off about how well it performs, and even if it's suitable.